# Who pays for Rescue response?

Tags: airport, emergency-services

When a plane has equipment failure, or any number of other issues, they may declare an emergency. Quite often, one result of that is that the fire and/or rescue vehicles at the airport will be dispatched to inspect for fire/hot brakes, perform emergency services, or other things for that plane.

Who covers the cost of that? The airline? The airport authority?

(Note, I am primarily interested in North American answers, but any will suffice)

Comment: It really depends, larger airports this is paid for by the airport, and by extension the landing fees it charges, along with other fees collected by the airport from the airlines/passengers. This can be augmented with local/federal funding and taxes. Some services are paid for by the airline or its insurer (like wreckage removal). Off field services can vary even more.

Comment: The emergency services generally need to be on standby at the airport anyway, so it's not clear to me that there is even a particular cost for something like that unless it starts causing overtime or consumables like water/foam are used.

Comment: @RonBeyer That looks amazingly like an answer. And yet it isn't one.